# Facebook get user like without permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I am working on facebook like button.
There is a redirect url after the user clicked like.
The problem is, if the user liked the page before. The like button cannot redirect to the url.

Is there any way to know whether a user liked a fan page or not?
I tried to request for the facebook permission "user_likes" but facebook rejected....

Comment: Facebook provides a page app with a signed_request that contains a "liked" property.  What platform/language did you build your page app on?

Comment: _" I tried to request for the facebook permission "user_likes" but facebook rejected...."_ **fan-gates are not allowed.** and there's no way to get user likes without permission

Comment: I am not woking on a facebook page app. It is a mobile site.